# 6;# appended to the front of values via lookup fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, workflow-lookup

I have a list with a name, email field, and position field.

The odd thing is when I call the value of the lookup in a workflow email, a **6;#** is appended to the front of all three fields.

There are no empty spaces.
How do I correct this, please?

Comment: are you allow multiple values in lookup field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to create a workflow variable with data type string.
- Set the value of the variable to Current Item , select the look up `return field value` as `Lookup value with comma`

[image]

- Use the new variable in your email as the following

[image]

Comment: M.Qassas < You're amazing. Thank you!!!!! ( Yet again. :) )

Comment: :( when I created the variable as shown in the first box, I get "lookup for string" NOT "lookup for Person or group" and only see return field as : "as string" and "lookup value for text". And in all I still get a # in front of the value. I have spent hours.. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: don't worry, let's trace your steps, should you tell me what's your lookup field settings in list settings

Comment: also what's the SharePoint platform that you are using it's workflow 2010 / 2013

Comment: I have a column named Approver.It is a lookup field to a list with names on one column ,email on another and job title on the third.
I created a local variable called "approverEmail" as a string.
I set the aforementioned to the currentitem:Approvers:email value.( from the lookup column)
In the email workflow "Participants"> Workflow Lookup for a User> I selected Data Source : workflow Variables and Parameters. Field from Source Variable: approverEmail. Return Field As: Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimited

Comment: In act all three fields called from the lookup Approver: approver, email and position from the list it came from have appending # characters to the front of them.
I am using SharePoint 2010. I am SO very grateful for your generosity, kindness and expertise.

Comment: no problem my bro, you are welcome at any time, but please don't go far to finish this issue,  should you tell me what is the data type of  email field ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50229/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-mike-rooker).

Comment: M.Qassas you really amaze me :) Thank you. Text Field.

Comment: Hey M.Qassas thanks again for all your help. I managed to work on over the weekend. I'm so grateful for you!

Comment: That's great news, and you are welcome :)